# Chart.js don't work when I open my app as a stand alone app in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, chart.js

I'm deploying my app and I have a dashboard implemented with Chart.js. When I tested my app in standard way, the dashboard works fine, but opening my app through a Google Chrome shortcut (within a window) the charts doesn't work. Just charts doesn't work in Chrome window mode.

The problem occurs in Windows 7, when I open the app directly from the shortcut, the charts doesn't work, but if I open the Google Chrome, and then open the app using the shortcut, the charts works fine.

Someone have an idea about that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look in the developer tools console to see if your getting any errors in your app. A fairly likely culprit is that you are including scripts within your html page. Chrome apps require that all scripts are external to your html and referenced using something like

`<script src="path/to/your/script.js">`

You'll have to do some DOM manipulation in your script file to add the charts to your page.

Comment: there is no error in the developer console tools and all scripts are external. The most strange is that, when I open Google Chrome and then, I open the app window the charts works fine, but if I just open the app window the charts doesn't work (tested on Windows 7 32 bit).